# HTACCESS - use spaces in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I must (want ;) use spaces in URLs. I make "cute" URLs via htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^StorageList.php/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z%+-]+)$ StorageList.php?type=$1&users_id=$2&parts_section=$3 [L]
```

But when I go to StorageList.php/Point/21/Ford Fiesta, my script don't get variable data.

Comment: @DaveJust What is the reasoning behind not using `mod_rewrite` for variables like this case? I have often used it for friendly URLs and haven't encountered issues before?

Comment: *MUST* use spaces in URLS? *REALLY*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex to allow spaces:

```
RewriteRule ^StorageList\.php/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+?)/?$ StorageList.php?type=$1&users_id=$2&parts_section=$3 [L,NC,NE,QSA]
```